# HTML - Placeholder for a DIV

Tags: css, html

I'd like to have a placeholder of sorts for my DIV tag, which appears when the DIV is not in focus and has no text. I know there are multiple SO links on this, but the common solution provided by everybody, doesn't seem to work for me. Following is the HTML and the CSS. Why is this not working?

**Code:**

```css
#composeBody:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(data-placeholder);
  color: #555;
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div id="composeBody" data-placeholder="Start composing your message..." contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: It's working for me. What's not working? Please define.

Comment: Its working properly. Convert your code to snippet and check

Comment: Works just fine, checkout http://jsfiddle.net/md0g6a4v/ . Maybe an (old) browser problem?

Comment: Yes, it's working. I'd closed the </div> in the next line, so it took the blanks as content. Hence it wasn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
there are lot of options using javascript, but if you want to do it in css.Try this:[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
}
```

html: div( contentEditable=true data-text="Enter text here")(/div)